# PostgreSQL UTC to UK Local Times

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I'm using postgreSQL 10.1.

I have datetimes that have been created in UTC, in timestamp without time zone columns.
I need to return these as the correct UK local time for each (GMT or BST).

I've been trying AT TIME ZONE, and time zones BST/GMT seem fixed to their own offsets, regardless of when in the year the timestamp occured.

AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London' seems to give me what i want, showing a UTC timestamp as GMT or BST correctly (in the small sample i've tried it on), though i can't find this time zone properly documented regarding its daylight savings rules.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or to a reliable alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct:

```sql
AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London'
```

The first assigns UTC to the timestamp, the second converts from UTC to the `Europe/London` time zone.

[Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) states:

> ... PostgreSQL uses the widely-used IANA (Olson) time zone database for information about historical time zone rules. ...

It also supports other forms of time zones, referenced in the same documentation, but `Europe/London` is an IANA time zone.  You can see it in the list of IANA time zones [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  You can also look at the details of how this time zone is defined by examining the TZDB sources [here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2019a/europe#L503-L508), or view a more human-readable history of time changes in London [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london).